# Всплывающие окна с изменением адресной строки

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать такие окна?
Пример - ВК. Когда нажимаешь на новость, то она появляется в всплывающем окне, а адрес страницы меняется на /wall6543_56432, к примеру. Если заново пройти по этой ссылке, то откроется страница с этой всплывающей новостью.
Я так понял, это все на аяксе. Подскажите, в какую сторону гуглить, а лучше укажите на какие-то примеры.

Answer (score 2):

Если вас интересует способ сменить URL текущей страницы - то это [History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

Comment: Сомневаюсь. что это то. Почитаю на досуге. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

[fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) вам поможет, удобный попап.

Comment: Внимательнее вопрос читайте.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

При помощи функции `history.pushState();`

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если посетитель перешёл по ссылке. 
   Если НЕ нужно, чтобы подобная страница открывалась без использования js (например, поисковыми системами), то достаточно сделать так, чтобы парсилась ссылка location.href для получения уникального идентификатора статьи в БД. Далее шёл ajax запрос на сервер для получения контента и вставки его во всплывающий блок.
2. Если посетитель кликнул на блок с краткой новостью.
   Необходимо отслеживать клик на новости, чтобы опять же при помощи ajax подгружать новость во всплывающий блок. Пример:

```
$('.short_news').on('click', function(){
  //Пример кода запроса на сервер
    $.ajax({
    'get_news': 1,
    'news_id' : id,
    success: function(data){
      $('#popup').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Как это относится к вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

При открытии окна используйте код:

`history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Title', '/index.php')`

Где 'Title' - имя тега который нужно исправить.

Comment: А как при открытии этой ссылки показывать контент, это уже решать вам.